# Why does this implementation of setting Javascript Map() values not work?

Tags: javascript, iteration, mapping

I'm working on a coding problem that looks to return the second repeated word in a sentence.

```
console.log(`
================================================================================
Write a function that takes a string \`s\` 
that contains one or more sentences. 
Return the second word to be repeated, if any. 

For example, the sentence: 
"I really like coding; coding is like breathing." 
should return the word "like".
================================================================================
`);

const wordCount = (s) => {
  const wordMap = new Map();

  const stringAry = s.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, " ").split(" ");
  
  let amount = 1;

  const filteredStringAry = stringAry.filter((s) => s);

  filteredStringAry.forEach((str) => {
    wordMap.has(str) ? wordMap.set(str, amount++) : wordMap.set(str, amount);
  });

  const duplicateWords = [];

  for (let [word, count] of wordMap) {
    count === 2 ? duplicateWords.push(word) : null;
  }

  console.log(duplicateWords[1]);
};

wordCount("I really like coding; coding is like breathing.");
```

These lines:

```
let amount = 1; 

 filteredStringAry.forEach((str) => {
    wordMap.has(str) ? wordMap.set(str, amount++) : wordMap.set(str, amount);
  });
```

If I hard code `2` for the truthy map() value and `1` for the falsy map() value, it works fine but here, the variable `amount` is not incrementing the way I'd expect.

Comment: Use `wordMap.get(str) + 1`.

Comment: How do you expect `amount` to be incremented? You only increase it if the map has the value. However, once increased, it's increased forever - the next time around `amount` would be `2`, so even if the map *doesn't* have a value, you'd still call `set(str, 2)`. Also `amount++` is a post-increment so, you'd *record* the initial value and *then* increment it.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I don't know where to place the original value. And where to increment.

Comment: Ok I figured it out thanks to @JonasWilms. 

`wordMap.get(str) ? wordMap.set(str, wordMap.get(str) + 1) : wordMap.set(str, 1)`